# Force Close: ColapsingToolbar ontouch

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, navigationview

I faced a problem in my project.
i have a CollapsingToolbarLayout in my project, when I scroll down and Toolbar Closed, and then after that if i scroll up, and touch on the image in the Collapsing Toolbar, app get a forced close and i see this Errors:

```
09-10 11:41:35.687  24804-24804/m.ex.as.myTemp E/InputEventReceiver﹕ Exception dispatching input event.
09-10 11:41:35.690  24804-24804/m.ex.as.myTemp E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
09-10 11:41:35.706  24804-24804/m.ex.as.myTemp E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'float android.view.MotionEvent.getX()' on a null object reference
            at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:9485)
            at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onTouchEvent(CoordinatorLayout.java:449)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2400)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2093)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2372)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1722)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2742)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2333)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8742)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4136)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4002)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3557)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3610)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3576)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3693)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3584)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3750)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3557)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3610)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3576)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3584)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3557)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5823)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5797)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5768)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5913)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
09-10 11:41:35.706  24804-24804/m.ex.as.myTempD/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-10 11:41:35.711  24804-24804/m.ex.as.myTemp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: m.ex.as.myTemp, PID: 24804
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'float android.view.MotionEvent.getX()' on a null object reference
            at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:9485)
            at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onTouchEvent(CoordinatorLayout.java:449)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2400)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2093)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2372)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1722)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2742)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2333)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8742)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4136)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4002)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3557)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3610)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3576)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3693)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3584)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3750)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3557)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3610)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3576)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3584)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3557)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5823)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5797)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5768)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5913)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

notice that i get the same erorr:

```
android.view.MotionEvent.getX()
```

in my project in the NavigationView, when i touche in the edge of screen for open the menu, and open it a little bit slowly, and stop there, but if i open it quick every thing is fine.
pn: for now, i just create an ontouchListner for handling the touch, but every one know it's not answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a bug in the design library `23.0.0` and even I faced a similar problem. It has been fixed now though in the latest version `23.0.1`. You should upgrade to that. Other workaround to fix the crash is to use the following code.

```
collapsingToolbar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

The [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183166) is logged here.